# Automatic timer @Schedule Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer

I'm a new user of Java EE and I'm developing an application that has to update weather periodically.
I created an automatic timer using the annotation, in order to update every 5 minutes. I would like to change to time dinamically ( an administrator can change it):

```
@Schedule(minute="*/5",hour = "*", persistent = false)
public void weatherUpdate(){
}
```

I would need an integer variable called frequency that contains the frequency of weather updates. I tried to do something like this, but this didn't worked:

```
int freq=5;

@Schedule(minute="*/freq",hour = "*", persistent = false)
public void weatherUpdate(){
}
```

Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is use a [TimerService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html), for example you can create programmatic timers.

**Eg.**

```java
@Singleton 
@Startup 
public class ProgrammaticTimer { 

    @Resource 
    TimerService timerService; 

    public void createTimer(String timerId, int frec){ 
        ScheduleExpression expression = new ScheduleExpression(); 
        expression.minute("*/"+freq).hour("*"); 
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(expression, new TimerConfig(timerId, true)); 
    } 

    @Timeout 
    public void execute(){ 
        System.out.println("----Invoked: " + System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    } 
}
```

To edit a frequency of a timer, first you need cancel the current timer and create new timer with the new value.

**Eg.**

```java
@Singleton 
@Startup 
public class ProgrammaticTimer { 

    @Resource 
    TimerService timerService; 

    public void createTimer(String timerId, int freq){ 
        ScheduleExpression expression = new ScheduleExpression(); 
        expression.minute("*/"+freq).hour("*"); 
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(expression, new TimerConfig(timerId, true)); 
    } 

    public void editTimer(String timerId, int freq){ 
        cancelTimer(timerId)
        ScheduleExpression expression = new ScheduleExpression(); 
        expression.minute("*/"+freq).hour("*"); 
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(expression, new TimerConfig(timerId, true)); 
    } 

    public void cancelTimer(String timerId) {
        if (timerService.getTimers() != null) {
            for (Timer timer : timerService.getTimers()) {
                if (timer.getInfo().equals(timerId)) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Timeout 
    public void execute(){ 
        System.out.println("----Invoked: " + System.currentTimeMillis()); 
    } 
}
```

See also: [Using the Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

I hope this help.

Comment: Where do I have to put my code to be executed? in execute method ?

Comment: @AleNegrini Yes, when a programmatic timer expires (goes off), the container calls the method annotated `@Timeout` in the bean’s implementation class. The `@Timeout` method contains the business logic that handles the timed event.

Comment: But is the code you wrote above already working ? Because I tried to paste it into my application but it doesn't work

Comment: is a example, you must adjust to your needs take a look in documentation. What application server you are using?